# Body-parser not working?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

using node 9, and express 4.  I cannot seem to get the body data shown. After checking other questions, most seem to be resolved using `bodyParser.urlencoded`, but that doesn't seem to help me. What am I doing wrong?

*server.js*

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

//not sure if i need urlencoded when just sending data from client
// app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
// app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true}));
// app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
const port = process.env.PORT || 8000;

const Cat = require('./Cat');
const Dog = require('./Dog');

app.route('/animals')
  .get(function (req, res)  {
    console.log(res.body);
    res.send({ Cat, Dog });
  })
  .patch(function (req, res)  {
    console.log('patch is working!');
    console.log(req.body);
  })

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`));
```

call in react looks like this, for now I'm just trying to get patch to show data. the get call works, and console.log 'patch is working' shows fetch is also being called, but there is no data on the body being shown.

*client call*

```
fetch('/animals', { method: 'PATCH', body: {name: 'kitten'} })
```

Answer (score 1):

To make request to be treated as JSON from react do so.

```
 fetch('/animals', {
   method: 'PATCH', // POST
   headers: {'Content-Type':'application/json'},
   body: {
    "first_name": 'kitten'
   } })
```

Comment: Thank you for your time, it's helped me understand the header a bit more.

I've edited the fetch in react to echo yours, but the req.body in server.js is showing as an empty object.  '{}'.     Am I missing something else possibly? (all other code is working fine).  I also tried turning it into a post, but that didn't work either.

I'm quite perplexed, as data is being sent in the get, and the fetch call shows it's running, I just can't grab the body!

Comment: Maybe try this : `body: JSON.stringify({ name: 'kitten' })`

Comment: can you check in the browser network tab what your data is going in request ?

Answer (score 0):

[`bodyParser.json()`](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/body-parser.html) will only parse a body when the `Content-Type` of the request matches the parser you are using, which in this case would be `application/json`.
Your request to your `PATCH` endpoint needs to include the `Content-Type` in the request.

Comment: Thank you, I added a content type as shown in himanshu's post on the react side, but still no luck.  I checked out the docs you linked and tried some methods in there as well, but ran out of options.  Could be a by product of no sleep and failing on this for 2 days, but it's been on as to why the calls work, just can't get the body still.